# Setting label text from other header files in Visual C++ 2010 .rc file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

Assume that you have a label in a legacy Visual C++ 2010 project, defined like so:

```
[foo.rc]
    LTEXT            "Foo",IDC_STATIC,42,42,42,42
```

In a resource (.rc) file.

Now, you want to generate the text based on constants you define in a header file, like so:

```
[foo.rc]
    LTEXT            FOO_TEXT,IDC_STATIC,42,42,42,42
```

Where FOO_TEXT was previously defined in some other way, for instance:

```
[bar.h]
    #define FROBNICATE "F"
    #define OO "o"
    #define ICANTTHINKOFMETASYNTACTICVARIABLESBEGINNINGWITHO "o"
    #define FOO_TEXT (FROBNICATE OO ICANTTHINKOFMETASYNTACTICVARIABLESBEGINNINGWITHO)
```

Only that that doesn't work, because .rc files are not header files, and the RC compiler complains, telling you:

```
[Build output]
    1>foo.rc(42): error RC2116: expecting number for ID
    1>  
    1>  
    1>foo.rc(42): error RC2108: expected numerical dialog constant
```

What would you do?

To clarify, yes, the entire string in question is known at compile-time, but it also needs to be constructed from smaller strings (in this case, version information and release category (development, release, and another one)). Of course, I could also write C++ code that does that, but that seems very inelegant to me.

So, is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to achive what you want without C++ code. See the comment to [this msdn articl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381061%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)e:

Don't use parens in #define
**The resource compiler is very limited in its understanding of directives**. So, for example, this:

```
#define RESTYPE_FILE     (256)
```

will silently get ignored, while this:

```
#define RESTYPE_FILE    256
```

will work. Obviously, trying to use expressions or anything complicated like that will silently fail, leaving you wondering why you can't load that resource.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't look like I will get around it. Thanks for the answer :)